# Can We debug javascript functions using visual studio?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm curious to know that can We debug javascript functions in visual studio, if its possible please let me know how. I'm working on asp.net web application project.

Comment: You can't debug client side code in visual Studio, you can debug node.js in visual studio. You can use chrome dev tools, firebug, or IE's dev tools to debug JavaScript.

Comment: I know there is a solution for that. I saw it in a presentation of Scott Hanselman, where he wanted to show that particular scenario on stage (unfortunately it didn't work live). But I do not remember the plugin he used.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug Javascript only if you will use Internet Explorer in conjunction with Visual Studio.
Otherwise, only via browser.